# How to extract the value corresponding to same head row and head column of a file?

Tags: text-processing

I have the following file

```
    1 2 3 4 5 
1   a b c d e
2   f g h i j
3   k l m n o
4   p k r s t
5   w x w z #
```

I want to extract the value corrponding to position 1,1 - 2,2 - 3,3- 4,4 and 5,5

i.e. the wanted output

```
1 2 3 4 5
a g m s #
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'FNR == 1 { sub("^ *", ""); print; ORS=" "; next } { print $FNR } END { printf("\n") }' file
1 2 3 4 5
a g m s #
```

This `awk` code does the following:

1. If the line is the first line, remove spaces from start of the line and print it. Then change the output record separator (`ORS`) to a space, and skip to the next line.
2. For all other lines, print the field corresponding to the line number.  The data will be printed with a trailing space, not a newline, due to the value of `ORS`.
3. At the end, output a single newline.

Comment: Consider changing FNR to NR: your script does not really support multiple files and is not a requirement. Consider removing the printf parentheses: it is a statement, not a function.

Comment: @Nethox Thanks for your comment. I tend to use `FNR` rather than `NR` (although I seem to have used `NR` too, I will change that) as I most often want to refer to the current record number "in this file", not over all. It signals intention and also allows the code (not just this one) to more easily be adapted to handle multiple input files. As for the `printf` thing. Yes, it's a statement, but I personally think it looks ugly without the parentheses (me being a C programmer). So it's a conscious choice based on personal aesthetics.

Answer (score 2):

In case your columns or rows are not sorted or rather rely on keywords:

```
awk 'BEGIN {IFS=" +"} 
     NR==1 {for ( i=1 ; i<=NF ; i++ ) { ihead[$i]=i+1 }
     NR>1 { print $1,$ihead[$1] }' file

file
    5 2 1 4 3 
4   a b c d e
1   f g h i j
2   k l m n o
5   p k r s t
3   w x w z #

result
4 d
1 h
2 l
5 p
3 #
```

Pipe it to `sort` for sorted output. For fitting the format as you requested, either pipe it to `datamash -t' ' transpose` (prerun it through `sort` for sorted output) or go for the more bulky way:

```
awk 'BEGIN {IFS=" +"} 
     NR==1 {for ( i=1 ; i<=NF ; i++ ) { ihead[$i]=i+1 ; head[$i]=$i }
     NR>1 { result[$1]=$ihead[$1] }
     END { for (a in head) printf head[a]" "
           printf "\n"
           for (a in head) printf result[a]" "}' file
```

In the latter (`awk`) case results are also sorted (alphanumerically by elements of *head*):

```
1 2 3 4 5 
h l # d p
```

Comment: Isn't this easier? `awk 'NR>1 {print $1, $($1)}' file | sort`

Comment: As said, I also included keyword headers as possibility. However you will have to pay attention and shift all fields by +1! (as entry 1 will otherwise result in the column heads and all other are shifted by 1). AND the head row must be sorted in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Since column and row indices in your file are consecutive numbers - you may rely on natural offset *row index --> to column index*:

```
$ awk 'NR == 1{ sub(/^ +/, ""); print; next }
      { sep= NR!=NF? FS:ORS; printf "%s%s", $NR, sep }' file
1 2 3 4 5
a g m s #
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html) (`mlr`):

```
$ tr -s ' ' < file | 
    mlr --inidx --opprint put -q 'NR>1 { @x[NR-1] = $[NR] }; end {emit @x}'
1 2 3 4 5
a g m s #
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, perhaps just

```
awk 'NR==1{print};NR>1 {printf $NR" "}' file | column -t
```

Output

```
1  2  3  4  5
a  g  m  s  #
```

Make it `column -t -o" "` if you want the original single character spacing

Answer (score 1):

Using the linux  desk calculator dc utility GNU version:

```
$ sed -Ee 's/(\S+)/[&]/g' file |
   dc -e "
    [q]sq
    [SM z0=p z0<a]sa
    [LMn 32an lm1-dsm0<p]sp
    [n32ancz]sr
    [zlN=r sz z0<b]sb
    [?z0=q lN1+sN lbx z0=?]s?
    ?zsm lax 10an 1sN l?x
   "
 1 2 3 4 5 
 a g m s #
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl : adjust the output record separator $\  and the current record.

```
$ perl -pale 's/^\s+//;
    ($_, $\) = ($F[$.-1], eof ? $/ : $") if $. > 1;
 ' file
```

Using GNU sed we can do a two pass over the input to generate the sed commands that will operate upon itself to get the output ;

```
$   sed -n 1!= file  |
    sed -e 's/.*/&s|(\\S+)|\&\\n|&/' \
        -e '$s/$/\n1b\ns|.*\\s(\\S+)\\n.*|\\1|/' \
        -e '$s|$|\nH;$!d;g;y/\\n/ /|' |
    sed -r -f - file |
    column -t
```